# Memory leak issue with curl javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, curl, memory-leaks

These last couple of days, i have been facing to an issue.I want to send data every 30 sec to a website (http://emoncms.org) thanks to curl and json. So i have created a script in order to refresh the php page, it's working but after a while i can see memory of the page skyrocketing.

I am using the wampserver 2.4 to do that.

```
   $MyApiKey="809b6187f38e0e617a4330bbde46ef21";
   $url='http://emoncms.org/input/post.json?apikey=809b6187f38e0e617a4330bbde46ef21&json={courant:200}';
   $ch=curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   unset($ch);
```

And here is the script for the page which is supposed to receive and to illustrate the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
var a=setInterval(function(){
$('#testbis').load('essaicomm.php').fadeIn("slow");
clearInterval(a);
delete(a);
test();
},20000);}
test();

</script>
```

I have also tried a more simple one:

```
var auto_refresh=setInterval(
function()
{
$('#bob').load('heure.php').fadeIn("slow");},10000);
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: version of PHP please

Comment: please go change your api key.

Comment: use setTimeout, not setInterval, and move your "var a" declaration out of test() and it should be ok. as is, it ques a new one every 20 seconds, so @ 40 there's 2, @ 60 there's 5, and @ 80 there's 11...

Comment: Thank you for your answer dandavis. I have tried this:

    var a = function () {
    $('#testbis').load('essaicomm.php').fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout(a, 20000);
    clearInterval(a);
    delete(a);
    };
    setTimeout(a, 20000);
    clearInterval(a);
    delete(a);

But the memory doesn't decrease at all. I have read that curl_init() can create memory leak but I didn't find out how to release memory used by each "curl call"...

Comment: I have been watching the memory into the timeline and it has the expected behavior but in the process list, my opera webpage increases steadly...